# ¿Cómo importar correctamente este tipo de libreria js?

Tags: javascript, librería

soy nuevo en la programacion y estoy intentando hacer unos calculos financieros de armortizacion, valor futuro, etc.
pude encontrar una libreria llamada [financejs.org](http://financejs.org/#start), donde enseñan como importarla con `npm` pero yo estoy usando laravel y por lo que busque `npm` es de algo relacionado con Nodejs (si se puede instalar en laravel algun ejemplo o como puedo hacerlo), entonces lo que hice fue descargar los archivos y los pegue en el proyecto, pero no se como usarlo correctamente.

en la pagina de la libreria me muestran esto:

**Ejemplo de uso**

```
var Finance = require('financejs');

   var finance = new Finance();


   // To calculate Amortization

   finance.AM(20000, 7.5, 5, 0);

   // => 400.76
```

Cómo puedo imcorporar todo eso en el segundo archivo `codigo.js`, para usar el  `finance.AM()` correctamente.

> si preguntan que tengo hecho o que he intentado, pues no se como hacerlo por eso pregunto, no tengo hecho nada por que no tengo idea de como se hace, no se los nombres tecnicos como para buscarlos en google o algo asi, es algo nuevo para mi.

en **Codigo.js** solo tengo una funcion donde obtengo los `input` con `id` que voy a utilizar para calcular la amortizacion, si es necesario incorporar me lo hacen saber, Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo estoy usando esa **librería** y tenia problemas con 3 métodos, pero ya lo pude solucionar era algo de la versión, si llegas a tener problema con los métodos, la solución que encontré fue utilizar una versión anterior a la que te ofrece la pagina (en la misma pagina de **financeJS** te proporcionan el **link** a **github**)

La forma de usarlo es super sencilla, de hecho la pagina te lo dice como se hace, entiendo que eres nuevo en esto, yo también lo soy.

suponiendo que ya tengas agregado el archivo `finance.js` al `html` simplemente en el archivo `js` en tu caso `codigo.js` puedes utilizar esta libreria así:

```
var metodos = new Finance()  //declaras la variable
var amortizacion= metodos.AM(20000, 7.5, 5, 0);  //aqui declaras una variable, esto para que lo puedas usar si lo quieres "imprimir"
console.log(amortizacion) //aquí solo lo muestras por consola.
```

y esto es lo que me muestra por consola.

[image: resultado_consola]

que según el ejemplo que proporciona **Financejs** es:

```
 finance.AM(20000, 7.5, 5, 0);
 // => 400.76
```

te darás cuenta que es el mismo resultado.

y ya luego si lo quieres mostrar en la vista, puedes hacerlo así:

```
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = amortizacion  // en caso de querer mostrar en un span.
document.getElementById('resultado').value = amortizacion  // en caso de querer mostrar en un input, si es que necesitaras guardarlo.
```

alguna duda, me la haces saber mientras pueda ayudar, con gusto lo haré.

Comment: no se por que no probe eso, creo que me centre en como se utiliza esto `var Finance = require('financejs');` que no me di cuenta que eso ya se omitia. ahora si me funciona y lo que comentas de "imprimir" si lo se hacer, de igual forma gracias por la sugerencia. otra cosa, serias tan amable de pasarme el link de la version que utilizaste?? para evitar errores y de paso me evito estar buscando jeje. gracias!

Comment: suele pasar que se pasen por alto algunas cosas.
el link del github es [FinanceJS](https://github.com/ebradyjobory/finance.js/tree/f53d8eaf9f710187d89510c98f90391aaa37c6ad).

Comment: Muchas gracias! por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

**1 opción**

Puedes usar algún bundler(es una herramienta que permite empaquetar todos tus scripts en un único script y así evitar varios scripts tags en tu html) como [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [parcel](https://parceljs.org/), [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/).

Te recomiendo mirar la documentación de webpack.

**2 opción**

Descargar la librería y añadir el tag `script` en tu html en el `header`. De esta manera, ya tendrás acceso a la funciones u objetos que proporciona la librería.

`<script src="ruta/carpeta/finance.js"></script>`

Comment: Gracias por responder, haber comento si se como imcorporar los archivo al html (descargue) eso ya esta, lo que no se hacer es como "consumir" (no se como se diria) y declarar  `var variable = new Finance();` para luego usar `variable.AM()` por que cuando lo definia asi no me hacia nada ni en `console.log()` mostraba algo.

Comment: si quieres pon el código de como lo tienes y se puede mirar